# During visual studio build, will the dll referenced from a different folder get copied to the applications bin folder

Tags: visual-studio, build

During visual studio build, will the dll referenced from a different folder get copied to the applications bin folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you've set it to do.

Right-click the DLL under "References" in Solution Explorer, and select "Properties". From there, you can change the "Copy Local" setting which determines whether or not the DLL is copied to the bin folder.